# How do I modify the UserAgent in webkit-sharp webview object?

Tags: c#, mono, webkit-sharp

WebKit.WebView has a Settings.UserAgent option, but that only has a get() method defind, so I can't set the value. I can't seem to find anywhere else that it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is how to do it...

Override the WebKit.WebSettings class and access the GLib.Object protected member SetProperty:

```
class ExposedWebSettings : WebKit.WebSettings {
    public void g_object_set(string name, GLib.Value value) {
        SetProperty(name, value);
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate this object and call g_object_set to set any property...

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
ExposedWebSettings settings = new ExposedWebSettings();
settings.g_object_set("user-agent", new GLib.Value("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120427 Firefox/15.0a1"));
webView.Settings = settings;
webView.Open ("http://www.google.com");
```

This is what GLib.Object.SetProperty looks like, by the way:

```
protected void SetProperty (string name, Value val)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup (name);
    Object.g_object_set_property (this.Raw, intPtr, ref val);
    Marshaller.Free (intPtr);
}
```